# Drawing track of multiple points using google maps

Tags: android, google-maps, maps, google-maps-android-api-2, tracking

I'm trying to build an application(android) to draw a route between multiple points, but i have problem that google services just give me a path between two points so is there any service that i can use where i can put my points and get the shortest path like between two points ? Any ideas..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just use the api to find a shortest path between two points with an additional constraint: must go through other selected points. 
Please refer this for more information: https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/directions/intro#Waypoints